# Angular Download JSON as separate files and Zipped

Tags: angular, typescript

I have been doing some research but unable to get it working

I have an array of JSON which I can call via subscribe method (which is calling REST API)

```
this.restapi.getData()
      .subscribe(
        results => {
        for (let each of results) {
        ...
        }
      });
```

each gets multiple results of JSON array..

What I want to do is to save them as individual files with filename as `each.name` (the structure has a name key) and export it via a download button zipped perhaps.. I was trying to use `export-from-json` package but not necessary.

Can you please help me please with the following

1. How to capture each into a separate file and then
2. How to zip them all and download it as a single file on the click of a button?

Is it possible without any hosting needs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This totally achievable on the client side !

A lib like [JSZip](https://github.com/Stuk/jszip) can fit your needs!  (Adding multiple files into a zip) , and you can use [FileSaver](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/) to save the file locally !

```
const foo = {foo: 'foo'};
const bar = {bar: 'bar'};

const zip = new JSZip();

zip.file('foo.json', JSON.stringify(foo));
zip.file('bar.json', JSON.stringify(bar));

zip.generateAsync({type:"blob"}).then(function(content) {
    saveAs(content, "example.zip");
});
```

Comment: Thanks.. Do you have one step further.. I have multiple this.restapi.getData1(), this.restapi.getData2() etc.. I want to call each of them with different folder structure for their json and finally zip them into a single zip "example.zip" ... I am guessing some async or something needs to be done.. but not sure how to do so.